# OpenSSL fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'x86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64

Tags: windows, visual-c++, openssl, 64-bit

I'm encountering a very frustrating error while trying to build OpenSSL on Windows 10. The error I get is

```
"lib" /nologo /out:providers\libdefault_static.lib @C:\Users\jcava\AppData\Local\Temp\nmF1AF.tmp
providers\common\libdefault-lib-bio_prov.obj : fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'x86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64
```

The steps I'm doing are running `perl Configure VC-WIN64A` then `nmake` both within the openssl directory that I cloned from Github. Im running all of this within a x64 command line prompt for VS 2019.

Cheers,
James

Answer (score 13):

For x64 you have to run your `perl Configure` and `nmake` commands from
**x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 201x**, not the **Developer Command Prompt for VS 201x**.

You can search for it in your Windows search bar. Make sure to right click it and run it in administrator mode.

If you've already compiled it incorrectly, you probably have to delete openssl and clone it again. Deleting the .obj files didn't solve it for me.

[Source](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/8836)

Comment: This solved a lot of confusion for me. Admin is required to install, but not to build.

Answer (score 3):

I had similar problem. It means that there are some object files that have been compiled already using x86 (in this case). Perhaps you started off using the x86 compiler.

If you delete all the object files (type `del /S *.obj` in your openssl directory) then run nmake again it should compile fine.

Alternatively you could re-clone the repository and start again.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same error using **Visual Studio Community 2022**.  Maybe I'm blind, but I couldn't find a *x64 Native Tools Command Prompt* anywhere.

For anyone who finds their way here and is using VSC2022: you can use the *Developer Command Prompt* and run `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat` before building OpenSSL v3.1.0.  Of course, your *vcvars64.bat* might be installed elsewhere.

And yes as others suggested, I had to remove the files from the previous failed builds.  I just used `nmake clean`.

And if you're building 32-bit versions, there's an equivalent *vcvars32.bat* script.

Comment: This worked. Just had to change "Community" to "Professional" since I'm using the paid VS.